# extracting h2 header from website using simplehtmldom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

im studying simple html dom.
as mentioned in their documentation, if we want to retrieve headers from website like , we would proceed as following:

```
  <?php

 include('simple_html_dom.php');

 $html = file_get_html('https://www.w3schools.com/');


 //to find h1 headers from a webpage
 $headlines = array();
 foreach($html->find('h2') as $header) {
 $headlines[] = $header->plaintext;
 }
 print_r($headlines);
 ?>
```

when i test this sample on my local server, it prints only:

```
  array ()
```

if i had well understood it should print:

```
 Python Php Java etc....everything that is inside <h2> tag.
```

am i missing something?

Comment: maybe you don't have internet connection? i've copy pasted your code and this is the output:`Array
(
[0] => Python ,
[1] => PHP ,
[2] => jQuery ,
[3] => Java ,
[4] => W3.CSS ,
[5] => Color Picker ,
[6] => Bootstrap ,
[7] => Exercises ,
[8] => Web Templates ,
[9] => How To Section ,
[10] => Web Certificates 
)` which is what you are expecting

Comment: Retested on distant server:     Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.w3schools.com/): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /srv/disk22/3502335/www/gigamarket.c1.biz/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php on line 82

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on bool in /srv/disk22/3502335/www/gigamarket.c1.biz/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simplehtmldom-test.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/disk22/3502335/www/gigamarket.c1.biz/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simplehtmldom-test.php on line 23

Comment: It would be better if you used a native drive (domdocument) so other developers can help you. Those errors should be pretty clear, `file_get_html` failed. Maybe you've crawled it too many times